# Pyspark - github actions

Tags: python, github, pyspark, github-actions

I can't understand how it works, that's enough to install pyspark in gihub action (agent) to actually have working spark. When I want to use pyspark locally it's required to download spark, set environment variables: SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME and install pyspark (as a client to spark).

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pyspark==3.4.0
    - name: Spark version
      run: |
        spark-shell --version
```

I thought that similar steps are required to set up spark on github actions as on local machine. There is a special action for spark [https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com), but it looks that is not very useful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To install pyspark, you also need java installed on your machine. Meanwhile, if what you wanna accomplish is in the scope of github action, I think you can do it just using python rather than pyspark. I'd be happy to help writing the solution in python.